# Discord bot on Heroku throws an error: agent ??= new https.Agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

This is related to my first question. I updated all of my codes. In my `bot.js` is:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

let ver = process.env.DISCORD_BOT;

client.once('ready', async () => {
  if (ver === 'production') {
    client.user.setActivity(`in code land`, { type: 'PLAYING' });
  } else {
    client.user.setActivity(`over ${client.guilds.cache.size} server(s)`, {
      type: 'WATCHING',
      status: 'IDLE',
    });
  }
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  console.log(`the prefix is ` + prefix);
});
```

`Procfile`:

```
worker: node bot.js
```

`package.json`:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production&&npm start",
    "development": "set NODE_ENV=development&&npm start"
  }
```

`.env`:

```
DISCORD_BOT= TOKEN
```

When I checked the Heroku application logs here's the error thrown:

> 2021-12-22T03:13:05.436081+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent
> ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive:
> true });
>
> 2021-12-22T03:13:05.436082+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^
>
> 2021-12-22T03:13:05.436082+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2021-12-22T03:13:05.436082+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token '??='

I've tried to search for the *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='"* and every single result is suggesting to update node.js to v16-17 but I'm already using the latest version of both Discord.js and Node.js.

Comment: If you've made changes to your code or have additional information, please add it to your existing question and don't create a new one for it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from discord.js and it's because you're using an older version of Node.js. The [logical nullish assignment operator (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) is only [available in node v15+](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment).

You might think that you're using the latest version of Node.js, but Heroku says that *"if a Node version isn't specified in the engine, the 14.x release will be used"*. You can add an `engines` prop to your `package.json` file to specify the version you need. As discord.js v13 [requires node.js v16.6+](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start), you can add the following:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.6"
  }
```

Or to request the latest v16, add this:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
```

Comment: After adding `engines` in `package.json` the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='` are gone. But It always says `State change from up to crashed`.

Comment: Last update. Last error's at my codes. But Finally! It's done! Thank you all guys!