# Cannot host discord bot on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, build, discord.js

I'm making a discord music bot with NodeJs, and I've been trying to host it on Heroku, but it keeps crashing with this problem

```
 /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:34
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
           ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bee25@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bee25@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-01-03T09:38:33.704796+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-03T09_38_33_700Z-debug.log
State changed from up to crashed
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bot-bee25.herokuapp.com request_id=e40f06e4-6d14-4cd4-ba4e-baa2091a87c9 fwd="216.245.221.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: Use a more up-to-date Node version on Heroku? Read e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot on Heroku throws an error: agent ??= new https.Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443889/discord-bot-on-heroku-throws-an-error-agent-new-https-agent)

Comment: I use Node 16. unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json` add this following code line:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x" //To get the latest node version
}
```